# jquery autocomplete restricted max items to ard 300 but it works in ie and others, any solution?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

```
var tags ="s1,s2,...,s1670";

$("#newtag0").autocomplete(tags, {
      minChars: 0,
      width: 310,
      selectFirst: true,
      multiple: true,
      cacheLength:1672,
      max:1672
});
```

This will work in IE 7 and 8, chrome and safari but in firefox it results only s388 last with no errors.. Means 4096 chars..

Is it browser restriction, need to figure it out..

Answer (score 3):

I encounter the same issue. The work around would be to do array static initalization on server side. For example, in jsp, I do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var survey_ds = [
            <%=StringUtil.getAllSurveyName()%>
        ];

        var tag_ds = [
            <%=StringUtil.getAllTag()%>
        ];
</script>
```

and use the array in js. I guess the static initialization is not on heap this time. And all those browsers could work with it.